# SQL Server behaviour change while using datetimeoffset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have been using SQL Server for quite sometime and noticed a change in behavior while using **datetimeoffset**.

Lets take an example of two queries, one is using normal string comparison in datetime values and one which is using **datetimeoffset** type viz

```
select * from (
    select cast('2019-09-06 11:28:05.757' as datetime) as test_date
) data where test_date < '2019-09-06 11:28:05.757'



DECLARE @P1 datetimeoffset;
set @P1 = '2019-09-06 11:28:05.757';

select * from (
    select cast('2019-09-06 11:28:05.757' as datetime) as test_date
) data where test_date < @P1
```

I executed the above queries in SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2019 and the difference comes in the execution of second query, where for SQL Server 2019 it gives the results as the corresponding date

[image]

I wanted to check if there is some change in behavior with respect to the datetimeoffset parameter type in the latest versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I don't follow bthe question here. You said you're questionimg the result in 2019; what's wrong with it?

Comment: i am saying that when we execute the second query in the older versions of SQLServer, it doesn't give any result, which seems to be correct as compared to SQLServer 2019 which gives the result. Is it about some precision based comparison that has been changed in SQLServer2019?

Comment: @Dale K: Yes Thanks, I did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you have both expected and also documented in [SQL Server 2016's breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15).

> Under database compatibility level 130, implicit conversions from **datetime** to **datetime2** data types show improved accuracy by accounting for the fractional milliseconds, resulting in different converted values. Use explicit casting to datetime2 datatype whenever a mixed comparison scenario between datetime and datetime2 datatypes exists. For more information, see this [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4010261).

With 2016 Microsoft updated the behaviour for converting from the old `datetime` data type to the newer ones to be more accurate. Previously a `datetime` value like `2019-09-06 11:28:05.757` converted to the `datetime2(7)` value `2019-09-06 11:28:05.7570000`, however, in 2016+ it is now accurately converted to `2019-09-06 11:28:05.7566667`. This is because a `datetime` is accurate to 1/300 of a second, *not* 1/1000, so the conversion before was actually adding time to the value.

For your query, you firstly have the `datetimeoffset(7)` value `2019-09-06 11:28:05.7570000`. You then compare that value to the `datetime` value `2019-09-06 11:28:05.757`. As the 2 data types are different one is implicitly converted to the other. `datetimeoffset` has a higher precendence, so the `datetime` value (`2019-09-06 11:28:05.757`) is converted to a `datetimeoffset` the value `2019-09-06 11:28:05.7566667`, which *is* less that your other `datetimeoffset` value `2019-09-06 11:28:05.7570000`.

As mentioned, in 2014 (and prior) SQL Server inaccurately converted the `datetime` value to `2019-09-06 11:28:05.7570000`, which *isn't* less than itself. This is why the behaviour differs.

If you want the same behaviour, I would suggest (as the breaking change does), using an explicit conversion, and convert to a `datetimeoffset(3)`. For example, the below does *not* return a result set in either instance:

```sql
DECLARE @P1 datetimeoffset;
SET @P1 = '2019-09-06 11:28:05.757';

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT cast('2019-09-06 11:28:05.757' as datetime) as test_date) data
WHERE CONVERT(datetimeoffset(3),test_date) < @P1;
```

[2014](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a9e825257542622dd0a80c36cecb7f78), [2019 (Linux)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=a9e825257542622dd0a80c36cecb7f78)

Answer (score -1):

Test case

```
select cast(test_date as datetimeoffset) d2ofs, @@version
from (
    select cast('2019-09-06 11:28:05.757' as datetime) as test_date
) data
```

Results:

```
d2ofs   (No column name)
2019-09-06 11:28:05.7566667 +00:00  Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU12) (KB4536648) - 13.0.5698.0 (X64) 
    Feb 15 2020 01:47:30 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

vs

```
d2ofs   (No column name)
2019-09-06 11:28:05.7570000 +00:00  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU-GDR) (KB4535288) - 12.0.6372.1 (X64) 
    Dec 12 2019 15:14:11 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8ca2e15c9bc718f606ea86ded06ee936)