# How does Microsoft SQL Server compare datetime to datetimeoffset values in a query statement?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, jdbc

I'm working with a legacy database (running on SQL Server 2019) which uses `datetime` for columns storing timestamp information and I'm trying to get a better handle on what SQL Server is doing under the hood when comparing a `datetime` value to a `datetimeoffset` value.

We're attempting to migrate some code to a new platform which will use the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC drivers. In order to run the database in Compatibility Level 150 (for SQL Server 2019), the Microsoft JDBC driver will translate all timestamps into `datetimeoffset` parameters. This is causing precision issues when the `datetime` value ends in either `3` or `7`.

I've been reading through other Stack Overflow response (such as [SQL Server behaviour change while using datetimeoffset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66964633/16607349) & [x][2]) and understand how SQL Server coerces a `datetime` value into `datetimeoffset`, but that coercion does not appear to be exactly what is happening in a `WHERE` clause on a SQL Statement.

For example, take the following SQL:

```
declare @tmp table (id int identity primary key, createDate datetime not null)
insert into
    @tmp
        (createDate)
    values
          ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.930')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.933')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937')

declare @input datetimeoffset = '2021-09-27 18:36:01.937'

select
    *
from
    @tmp
where
    createDate = @input
```

When running this query, you get no matches.

I know that if you run `select cast('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937' as datetimeoffset)` you get `2021-09-27 18:36:01.9370000 +00:00` and if you run `select cast(cast('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937' as datetime) as datetimeoffset)` you get `2021-09-27 18:36:01.9366667 +00:00`, so that ***potentially*** make sense on why the values might not match if the `createDate` column is being implicitly converted to a `datetimeoffset`. However, when I look at the execution plan this does not appear to be the case and if I change the code to:

```
declare @tmp table (id int identity primary key, createDate datetime not null)
insert into
    @tmp
        (createDate)
    values
          ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.930')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.933')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937')

declare @input datetimeoffset = '2021-09-27 18:36:01.9366667 +00:00'

select
    *
from
    @tmp
where
    createDate = @input
```

I still do not get a match, which would appear to mean that `createDate` is not being coerced into a `datetimeoffset` datatype for comparison. Now if I explicitly cast the `datetimeoffset` to `datetime`, I do get a match:

```
declare @tmp table (id int identity primary key, createDate datetime not null)
insert into
    @tmp
        (createDate)
    values
          ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.930')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.933')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937')

declare @input datetimeoffset = '2021-09-27 18:36:01.937'

select
    *
from
    @tmp
where
    createDate = cast(@input as datetime)
```

Or if I try to find match the `2021-09-27 18:36:01.930` value, I do not need to explicitly cast the value:

```
declare @tmp table (id int identity primary key, createDate datetime not null)
insert into
    @tmp
        (createDate)
    values
          ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.930')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.933')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937')

declare @input datetimeoffset = '2021-09-27 18:36:01.930'

select
    *
from
    @tmp
where
    createDate = @input
```

This tells me there is some kind of conversion going on, but I cannot figure out what's happening under the hood.

Can anyone help me understand what SQL Server is doing under the hood when it runs the following?

```
declare @tmp table (id int identity primary key, createDate datetime not null)
insert into
    @tmp
        (createDate)
    values
          ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.930')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.933')
        , ('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937')

declare @input datetimeoffset = '2021-09-27 18:36:01.937'

select
    *
from
    @tmp
where
    createDate = @input
```

I am trying to see if there is some way to format timestamp data so that all the existing code will not break. I could drop just drop the millisecond precision to the 1/100 (instead of 3.33ms precision), but I would like to keep as much precision as possible. I originally started down the path of converting the `datetime` values to `datetime2`, but due to the volume of data, indices, stats, etc. around the data converting everything would require a fair amount of downtime. Not to mention the code uses various `datetime` math tricks that would need to be refactored.

I know I could go through all the code and also add explicit conversions of the `datetimeoffset` to `datetime` as well, but some of the code is being generated by fluent SQL builders so doing that is not exactly straightforward either.

Lastly, I know I could convert the values to a `varchar(23)` field and allow SQL Server to do the implicit conversion that way, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

So, if anyone can shed light on what SQL Server is doing internally to compare the `datetime` to `datetimeoffset` values, I would greatly appreciate it.

> **RANT** — I really don't know why Microsoft changed SQL Server 2016 to convert values like `2021-09-27 18:36:01.937` to `2021-09-27 18:36:01.9366667` when casting to `datetimeoffset` and
> `datetime2`. Especially since casting a `datetimeoffset(3)` or
> `datetime2(3)` to a `datetimeoffset` would result in
> `2021-09-27 18:36:01.9370000 +00:00`. For example:
>
> ```
> select 
>     cast(cast('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937' as datetime) as datetimeoffset) as [datetime]
>   , cast(cast('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937' as datetimeoffset(3)) as datetimeoffset) as [datetimeoffset(3)]
>   ,   cast(cast('2021-09-27 18:36:01.937' as datetime2(3)) as datetimeoffset) as [datetime2(3)]
> ```
>
> Results in:
> | datetime | datetimeoffset(3) | datetime2(3) |
> |--|--|--|
> | 2021-09-27 18:36:01.9366667 +00:00 | 2021-09-27 18:36:01.9370000 +00:00 | 2021-09-27 18:36:01.9370000 +00:00 |
>
> It would seem to be more consistent if they were all cast the same
> way. I know the change was supposedly made to improve precision
> accuracy, but my guess is it causes way more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem here is the **implicit** conversion. As you have noted, when you convert a `datetime` to a `datetimeoffset` on **recent** versions of SQL Server (SQL Server 2016+), the value is correctly converted to be accurate to 1/300th of a second. For example the time `18:36:01.937` when converted to a `datetimeoffset(7)` (or even a `datetime2(7)`) would be `18:36:01.9366667`. *(This is not the case on older versions of SQL Server, that would incorrectly convert the value to `18:36:01.9370000`.)*

You define your parameter as a `datetimeoffset`, **no precision** (bad idea), so this defaults to a `datetimeoffset(7)`. As such the value `2021-09-27T18:36:01.937` becomes `2021-09-27T18:36:01.9370000+00:00`.

The `datetime` value here is implicitly converted to a `datetimeoffset` as the latter has a higher [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). So your 3 values become:

```
2021-09-27T18:36:01.9300000+00:00
2021-09-27T18:36:01.9333333+00:00
2021-09-27T18:36:01.9366667+00:00
```

As you can see, none of these are the same value as your variable `@input`, which as the value `2021-09-27T18:36:01.970000+00:00`.

One would *think* therefore that defining the precision of `@input` to be `3` would fix this, alas it does not. It seems that behind the scenes SQL Server still implicitly converts the `datetime` to a `datetimeoffset(7)` when it does it's comparison.

So the solution is the therefore use explicit casting, which is also stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#converting-other-date-and-time-types-to-the-datetime2-data-type):

> Under database compatibility level 130, implicit conversions from datetime to datetime2 data types show improved accuracy by accounting for the fractional milliseconds, resulting in different converted values, as seen in the example above. Use explicit casting to datetime2 datatype whenever a mixed comparison scenario between datetime and datetime2 datatypes exists. For more information, refer to this [Microsoft Support Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/sql/database-design/sql-server-azure-sql-database-improvements).

As the table you are querying has a `datetime` you want to explicitly convert your parameter *to* a `datetime`, not convert the column, to maintain SARGability: So the correct query you want is:

```sql
DECLARE @tmp table (id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                    createDate datetime NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @tmp (createDate)
VALUES ('2021-09-27T18:36:01.930'),
       ('2021-09-27T18:36:01.933'),
       ('2021-09-27T18:36:01.937');

DECLARE @input datetimeoffset(3) = '2021-09-27T18:36:01.937';

SELECT createDate
FROM @tmp
WHERE createDate = CONVERT(datetime, @input);
```

If it were the other way round, and your column was a `datetimeoffset` and the parameter a `datetime` then you would convert said parameter to a `datetimeoffset(3)`:

```sql
DECLARE @tmp table (id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                    createDate datetimeoffset NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @tmp (createDate)
VALUES ('2021-09-27T18:36:01.930'),
       ('2021-09-27T18:36:01.933'),
       ('2021-09-27T18:36:01.937');

DECLARE @input datetime = '2021-09-27T18:36:01.937';

SELECT createDate
FROM @tmp
WHERE createDate = CONVERT(datetimeoffset(3), @input);
```

---

To address your "rant":
Because the "new" method is more accurate (as I state earlier). The `datetime` value `2021-09-27T18:36:01.937` is ***not*** the value `2021-09-27T18:36:01.9370000~`. A `datetime` is accurate to 1/300 of a second. This is why `datetime` values all end in `0`, `3`, or `7`; the latter 2 are `0.0033333~` and `0.0066666~` seconds rounded to 3 decimal places. As a result when you convert a `datetime` value to a `datetime2(7)`, for example, it makes perfect sense that the converted value respects the prior accuracy, and so the `datetime` value `2021-09-27T18:36:01.937` is converted to the `datetime2(7)` value `2021-09-27T18:36:01.9366667` (which is `2021-09-27T18:36:01.9366666666~` rounded to precision of 7).

Comment: Thanks for the input.

What's confusing is that the execution plan does not show any implicit conversion. Also, in my example above if I explicitly declare the @datetimeoffset as ```2021-09-27 18:36:01.9366667 +00:00``` the query still does not return any values.

The reason my example has no precision for the ```datetimeoffset``` is because the JDBC driver is not generating one, and that's out of my control.

As far as doing an explicit conversion, I know that works, but there are places in our application stack where that's an issue. That's why I'm trying to find away around it.

Comment: Do you know of a way w/out the explicit conversion to get the where clause to match w/out giving the ```datetimeoffset``` precision?

Comment: No, and as mentioned, the documentation **explicitly** tells you to use **explicit** conversion, @dswitzer2 .

Comment: Since we have some third party fluent SQL builders being, the explicit casting becomes a problem. I wish the Microsoft JDBC drivers had an option like the Progress DataDirect JDBC driver's ```DateTimeInputParameterType``` which allows you to specify to use ```datetime``` instead of ```datetimeoffset```.

One way around the problem is to not use ```java.sql.timestamp``` at all, but instead just use a string and have the varchar field implicitly cast to ```datetime``` but that feels ugly. 

/cc: @larnu

Comment: Sounds like the *real* question you want to ask if how to pass a `datetime` in JDBC, @dswitzer2 . That, however, needs to be asked as a new question.

Comment: I know the answer to that. There is not when using the Microsoft JDBC driver. I've already opened up a Github issue to address this (https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1590). I was just hoping there was a way to pass my value which would end up matching the conversion SQL Server is doing under the hood, which does not appear to be possible.

Comment: Note that if you're using a procedure, @dswitzer2 , then you would be able to define the parameters with the appropriate data type(s) and that wouldn't be an issue.